# Xcode 12 and Carthage hell

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

It seems that there are tons of issues with Carthage and Xcode 12 ([see here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019))

I'm trying to follow the workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-693302447) but I'm still getting the same error message from Carthage.

```
*** Building scheme "Lottie_iOS" in Lottie.xcodeproj
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 1:
    /usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create .......blablabla
```

I'm wondering, is there a way to skip simulators and compile frameworks just for real devices?! this would be a temporary solution to be able to work...

Comment: I resolved this by `wcarthage`.
Find solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984866/7124289

Comment: It looks like a major headache, multiple frameworks seem to be totally borked with the GitHub comments proposing some brutal hacks to get it running :(